# Cannot Mount Floppy Drive

Tags: mount, floppy

since I got my Floppy Drive to be found by the system, I trouble with mounting it!

Some specs:

- Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS,
- EIDE-Connected FDD,
- installed packages for this subject: `udisk2`and `fdutils`

I also got the assumed entries in `fstab`  `80-udisks2.rules` , the `floppy` module is loaded and I also can format the disk via `fdformat`, but I cannot read it. Tried everything with root and as user in group "floppy"

Some results of commands I tried:

- `root@derinity:~# fdmount
  fdmount (/dev/fd0): Can't access /fd0: No such file or directory`
- `root@derinity:~# udisksctl mount -p /dev/fd0
  (udisksctl mount:1334): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_object_manager_get_object: assertion 'g_variant_is_object_path (
  Error looking up object with path /dev/fd0`
- `root@derinity:~# fdmount -l
  NAME   TYPE  STATUS
  fd0  1440K  not mounted`
- `root@derinity:~# fdformat /dev/fd0
  Double-sided, 80 tracks, 18 sec/track. Total capacity 1440 kB.
  Formatting ... done1
  Verifying ... Read: : Input/output error
  Problem reading track/head 0/0, expected 9216, read -1` [ADDED]

Hopefully,

dor_sax

Comment: Are there *any* `/dev/fd*` entries?

Comment: Yes, `/dev/fd0`

Comment: You say you can format it, have you done so? Have you created a filesystem on the disk that can be mounted?

Comment: I added the Output of `fdformat` right now. I assume I din`t create a FileSystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is from memory — I haven't had a floppy drive in nearly two decades.)

After formatting a floppy, it doesn't have a filesystem on it — so you need to create one before mounting it. E.g., to put a FAT filesystem on it, you'd do `mkfs.vfat /dev/fd0` (plus any options for label, etc.) Or you could put ext2 on it with `mkfs.ext2 /dev/fd0`; ext3/4 is likely not possible because the journal is much larger than a floppy.

Then it ought to mount normally, e.g., with `mount /dev/fd0 /media/floppy`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `superformat`, which will format the floppy and create a DOS file system with the appropriate parameters (using `mtools`’ `mformat`); for example,

```
superformat /dev/fd0 hd
```

to format a 1440K disk.

However even `fdformat` should be able to verify your formatted floppy without problem, so there’s something else wrong somewhere...